# How to implement iperf module for Bandwidth monitoring in this python chatroom?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, iperf, iperf3

https://iperf.fr/iperf-doc.php
https://iperf.fr/

```
    //server.py

    import socket
    import select
    import sys
    from thread import *

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "Correct usage: script, IP address, port number"
        exit()

    IP_address = str(sys.argv[1])

    Port = int(sys.argv[2])

    server.bind((IP_address, Port))

    server.listen(100)

    list_of_clients = []

    def clientthread(conn, addr):

        conn.send("Welcome to this chatroom!")

        while True:
                try:
                    message = conn.recv(2048)
                    if message:

                        print "<" + addr[0] + "> " + message

                        message_to_send = "<" + addr[0] + "> " + message
                        broadcast(message_to_send, conn)

                    else:
                        remove(conn)

                except:
                    continue

    def broadcast(message, connection):
        for clients in list_of_clients:
            if clients!=connection:
                try:
                    clients.send(message)
                except:
                    clients.close()

                    remove(clients)

    def remove(connection):
        if connection in list_of_clients:
            list_of_clients.remove(connection)

    while True:

        conn, addr = server.accept()

        list_of_clients.append(conn)

        print addr[0] + " connected"

        start_new_thread(clientthread,(conn,addr))    

    conn.close()
    server.close()
```

The client side script will simply attempt to access the server socket created at the specified IP address and port. Once it connects, it will continuously check as to whether the input comes from the server or from the client, and accordingly redirects output. If the input is from the server, it displays the message on the terminal. If the input is from the user, it sends the message that the users enters to the server for it to be broadcasted to other users.

```
    //client.py

    import socket
    import select
    import sys

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "Correct usage: script, IP address, port number"
        exit()
    IP_address = str(sys.argv[1])
    Port = int(sys.argv[2])
    server.connect((IP_address, Port))

    while True:

        sockets_list = [sys.stdin, server]

        read_sockets,write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list,[],[])

        for socks in read_sockets:
            if socks == server:
                message = socks.recv(2048)
                print message
            else:
                message = sys.stdin.readline()
                server.send(message)
                sys.stdout.write("<You>")
                sys.stdout.write(message)
                sys.stdout.flush()
    server.close()
```